# jQuery show new element after dom change

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I found many ways to operate on new elements after DOM change but all works with events. I just want `on click` hide element 1 than replace it with 2 with `display:none` and show it.

My code so far:

```
/*
     *  EDIT COMMENT
     */
    jQuery(document).on('click',options.targets.container+' '+options.targets.comment_edit, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = e.target;
        target = jQuery(target).parent();
        var comment_content = jQuery(target).find('.comment_content');          
        var comment_content = jQuery(comment_content).text();


        jQuery(target).find('.comment_content').hide(400,function(){
            jQuery(target).find('.comment_content').replaceWith('<textarea style="display:none" class="'+options.targets.comment_edit_form.replace('.','')+'">'+comment_content+'</textarea>');


            //not working
            jQuery(target).delay(400).find(options.targets.comment_edit_form.replace('.','')).show(400)

            console.log(jQuery(target).find(options.targets.comment_edit_form.replace('.','')))
        });


    })
```

I want to show new element just after i do replacing.
Problems are 2:
1: I can't get new element with jquery because it is added;
2: I can't display it after other function is done.

Answer (score 0):

Search element **after** insertion.

Modify your code as

```
jQuery(document).on('click',options.targets.container+' '+options.targets.comment_edit, function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = e.target;
    target = jQuery(target).parent();
    var comment_content = jQuery(target).find('.comment_content');          
    var comment_content = jQuery(comment_content).text();


    jQuery(target).find('.comment_content').hide(400,function(){
        jQuery(target).find('.comment_content').replaceWith('<textarea style="display:none" class="'+options.targets.comment_edit_form.replace('.','')+'">'+comment_content+'</textarea>');
      //show after  ( put your code here )
      jQuery(target).find('textarea').show();
    });
})
```

http://jsbin.com/pirinocuku/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Code dump is not useful

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I created an element:

```
    var dialogDiv = document.createElement("div");
    $("body").append(dialogDiv);
    $(dialogDiv).html('<p>' + text + '</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did wrong was
`jQuery(target).find(options.targets.comment_edit_form.replace('.','')).show(400)`
`options.targets.comment_edit_form` is class and i remove `.` from it so it couldnt find an element;

Changed to:

```
jQuery(document).on('click',options.targets.container+' '+options.targets.comment_edit, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = e.target;
        target = jQuery(target).parent();
        var comment_content = jQuery(target).find('.comment_content');          
        var comment_content = jQuery(comment_content).text();


        jQuery(target).find('.comment_content').hide(400,function(){
            jQuery(target).find('.comment_content').replaceWith('<textarea style="display:none" class="'+options.targets.comment_edit_form.replace('.','')+'">'+comment_content+'</textarea>');

            jQuery(target).find(options.targets.comment_edit_form.replace('.','')).show(400)
        });
    })
```

My bad, sorry guys